# app.R run app local host error resolved when published to shinyappio

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, aes, reactive

I'm following Kunaal Naik's Shiny_Dashboards reactive example and tried reproducing a simpler data set, but I'm getting a mapping error, "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x".  What am I doing wrong?

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
SalesRep <- c("Amy","Amy", "Amy", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe")
QTR <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3")
Sales <- c(10, 20, 30, 5, 10, 15)
sales <- data.frame(SalesRep, QTR, Sales)

  #Summarize Data and then Plot
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$sel_SalesRep)
    df <- sales %>% filter(SalesRep %in% input$sel_SalesRep) %>%  group_by(QTR) %>% summarise(Sales = sum(Sales))
  })
  
  #Plot 
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    g <- ggplot(data(), aes(y = Sales, x = QTR))
    g + geom_bar(stat = "sum")
  })
}

ui <- basicPage(
  h1("R Shiny interactive Bar Chart using Reactive and Render"),
  selectInput(inputId = "sel_SalesRep",
              label = "Choose Sales Rep",
              list("Amy","Joe")),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your `data` reactive is `null` because you assign the result of filtering your base data to a local variable rather than returning it. Delete `df <-`.

Comment: That certainly makes sense, but I'm still getting the same error; did it work for you?

Comment: Yes.  It does work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the education - bit by bit.  My error appears to derive from "Values" that are created with that dataframe.  If I rm() them then it works, except that I get an old error that "QTR" is not found.) You're getting a bar plot reactive by SalesRep with the sum of Sales by QTR?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you assign it to `df` within the `reactive` function or not - it'll still return the data as `<-` is a function with an [invisible return](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html?q=return#invisible) (of the value being assigned). I also am not getting any errors! my only suggestion would be checking the version of R/ggplot2/shiny you're running (you could paste the output of `sessionInfo()` above) or running in a completely fresh session?

Comment: It's a puzzle.  shiny_1.7.1 and ggplot2_3.3.5 versions appear to be current.  When I published this to shinyapps.io then it worked as expected, but the local host continued to show an error.  I'm a novice with logs, but I'll try to run it on a different machine.  Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be my local host on Ubuntu.  I ran the same code on a windoz machine and it worked as expected.  Thanks again for taking the time - you guys are the best!